# Mongoose Schema for Array of enums

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongoose, enums, mongoose-schema

I am expecting an output like

```
...,
"property": ["ENUM1", "ENUM2", "ENUM3"],
...
```

and these enums are of `String` type.

Mongoose Schema which I've built looks like the following (and producing error) -

```
...,
property: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['ENUM1', 'ENUM2', 'ENUM3'],
            required: true
        }],
...
```

Error - Mongoose is treating the request parameters of the property as one String and throwing error mentioning the string do not exist as an enum.

Comment: Found an issue in mongoose github repo but couldn't figure out the solution from it - https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/661